# Can we edit our code while running the application

Tags: c#, debugging

i did this work Tools->Options->Debugging 'Break all processes when one process
breaks' is enabled that time also same problem existing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio has a feature called [Edit and Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379578%28VS.80%29.aspx). This means you can break the execution, do the change, and then resume it (providing that the changes can be compiled and that the change is [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927%28VS.80%29.aspx) by Edit and continue).

In other words, you cannot exactly change the code while the app is **running**, but you can break it shortly and change the source using the debugger.

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio supports "Edit and Continue": a feature which allows you to pause using the debugger, edit your code, then resume execution. An article on Edit and Continue in C# is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379578%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can't if you are target a 64 bit machine however.

Comment: Actually, you can debug on a 64-bit *machine*, but the target CLR cannot be 64-bit (you would have to set target to x86). Not sure if this issue is going to be solved in VS2010.

Comment: Update from the docs: "Edit and Continue is supported for 64-bit projects that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1."